# Realm swift update List writing each runtime

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

My objects

```
   class RealmConversation: Object {

        @objc dynamic var id = ""
        var show = List<Show_id>()
        var show_ids: [String] {
            get {
                return show.map { $0.show_id }
            }
            set {
                show.removeAll()
                show.append(objectsIn: newValue.map {Show_id(value: [$0])})
            }
        }
        override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
            return ["show_ids"]
        }
        override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
            return "id"
        }
    }

class Show_id:Object {
    @objc dynamic var show_id = ""
}
```

appending viewcontroller

```
 newSpecimen.show_ids = ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
    realm.add(newSpecimen, update: true)   
    self.realmconversation = newSpecimen
```

result is runtime alway increasing x2 show_ids
how to update string list item 
**runtime 1**
[image]
**runtime 2**
[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yes i solved problem, but am not sure its good idea :),

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: here Show_id.id == con.id+show, con.id is unique then list id's are not containing in multiple times. thats all.  
for create in createCon.show{
            let showid = Show_id()
            showid.id = "\(createCon.id)\(create)"
            showid.conid = createCon.id
            showid.show = create
            con.show.append(showid)
 }
var show = List<Show_id>()
class Show_id:Object {
    objc dynamic var id = ""
    objc dynamic var show = ""
    objc dynamic var conid = ""
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

Answer (score 0):

> If you don’t want to save a field in your model to its Realm, override
>   Object.ignoredProperties(). Realm won’t interfere with the regular
>   operation of these properties; they’ll be backed by ivars, and you can
>   freely override their setters and getters. [Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)

for that before you adding new object, you should check if show_ids contains the ids that you want to add or not.

Comment: thank you for responsing, but check is useless i think, if i check that List is available and match i will skip, else exist not match i will update that list update is always writing realm runtime always +1 time writing